# Unable to grab an image with cheerio/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, screen-scraping, cheerio

My problem is pretty straightforward. I am trying to console log the URL of an image from the amazon link bellow. Either from a more precise selection

So I've spent the majority of the time attempting t select the id/class of the link but seem to only get the as close as #imgTagWrapperId which returns a lot of redundant information. In theory I should be able to grab the links with regex narrowing things down, but for the life of me I can only seem to replace the text i return and not simply grab it. Alternatively I have as stated attempted to grab the img src itself, only to return a nonsensical string of code. When I view page source the same ball of text appears there but not when I inspect elements directly.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request(`http://amazon.com/dp/B079H6RLKQ`, (error,response,html) =>{
    if (!error && response.statusCode ==200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const productTitle = $("#productTitle").text().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');

        const prodImg = $(`#imgTagWrapperId`).html();

        console.log(productTitle);

        console.log(prodImg);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
})
```

This current code returns the product title faithfully but returns this for the prodImg output:

```
<img alt="Samsung Galaxy S9 G960U 64GB Unlocked 4G LTE Phone w/ 12MP Camera - Midnight Black" src="
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIfIiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/2wBDAQoLCw4NDhwQEBw7KCIoOzs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozv/wAARCAEsARYDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL 

...(this nonsense goes on for a mile) ....

" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SL1500_.jpg"  class="a-dynamic-image  a-stretch-horizontal" id="landingImage" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX522_.jpg&quot;:[564,522],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX342_.jpg&quot;:[369,342],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX679_.jpg&quot;:[733,679],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX425_.jpg&quot;:[459,425],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX466_.jpg&quot;:[503,466],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX569_.jpg&quot;:[615,569],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX385_.jpg&quot;:[416,385]}" style="max-width:679px;max-height:733px;">
            </div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help and guidance with this. I Have exhausted all other usual sources and am ready to be called an idiot.

EDIT:

Someone wanted the html for before and after selection, Ill oblige but it might be better to just view the page source in the link and ctrl+ f. Wall of text bellow.

```html
<div class="variationUnavailable unavailableExp">
    <div class="inner">
        
        <div class="a-box a-alert a-alert-error" aria-live="assertive" role="alert"><div class="a-box-inner a-alert-container"><h4 class="a-alert-heading">Image Unavailable</h4><i class="a-icon a-icon-alert"></i><div class="a-alert-content">
            <span class="a-text-bold">
                Image not available for<br/>Color:
                <span class="unvailableVariation"></span>
            </span>
        </div></div></div>
    </div>
</div>




<!-- Append onload function to stretch image on load to avoid flicker when transitioning from low res image from Mason to large image variant in desktop -->
<!-- any change in onload function requires a corresponding change in Mason to allow it pass in /mason/amazon-family/gp/product/features/embed-features.mi -->
<!-- and /mason/amazon-family/gp/product/features/embed-landing-image.mi -->



<ul class="a-unordered-list a-nostyle a-horizontal list maintain-height">

        <span id="imageBlockEDPOverlay"></span>



 <li class="image item itemNo0 selected maintain-height"><span class="a-list-item">
     <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
         <div id="imgTagWrapperId" class="imgTagWrapper">
             <img alt="Samsung Galaxy S9 G960U 64GB Unlocked 4G LTE Phone w/ 12MP Camera - Midnight Black" src="
data:image/jpeg;base64,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







" data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SL1500_.jpg"  class="a-dynamic-image  a-stretch-horizontal" id="landingImage" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX522_.jpg&quot;:[564,522],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX342_.jpg&quot;:[369,342],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX679_.jpg&quot;:[733,679],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX425_.jpg&quot;:[459,425],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX466_.jpg&quot;:[503,466],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX569_.jpg&quot;:[615,569],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81%2Bh9mpyQmL._SX385_.jpg&quot;:[416,385]}" style="max-width:679px;max-height:733px;">
         </div>
     </span>
 </span></li>




<li class="mainImageTemplate template"><span class="a-list-item">
    <span class="a-declarative" data-action="main-image-click" data-main-image-click="{}">
        <div class="imgTagWrapper">
            <span class="placeHolder"></span>
        </div>
    </span>
</span></li>
```

Comment: please give us few a html tag before img tag and after img tag.

Comment: Hello! The prodImg output which you have successfully returned does have a `data-old-hires` attribute which is an image link. You can grab that link  by doing `$(''#landingImage'').attr('data-old-hires')` or you can also get the src which is a base64 encoded version of the URL.

Comment: @WilliamGunawan I posted the HTML in my edit.

Comment: @RishiRaj Thank you my good sir. This method is selecting the data-old-hires, but I would be very interested in learning how to decode the base64 back into a url.

Comment: I think the issue is not with the code itself, it is that amazon is requiring a captcha when doing requests like these, what I get in the response HTML is: `                <h4>Enter the characters you see below</h4>
                <p class="a-last">Sorry, we just need to make sure you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is accepting cookies.</p>`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rishi Raj for giving a quickfix solution.   $('#landingImage').attr('data-old-hires'). I was also adding a unnecessary .html() to the const which had gotten in the way. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply target the image directly and get the url with `.attr('src')`?

```js
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('http://amazon.com/dp/B079H6RLKQ', (error,response,html) => {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const productTitle = $('#productTitle').text().replace(/\s\s+/g, '');

        const prodImg = $('#landingImage').attr('data-old-hires');

        console.log(productTitle);

        console.log(prodImg);
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: This practice leads to a return of undefined.

Comment: Hm, just tried on the actual page with javascript off, the `src` attribute is a base64 encoded image, so I switched to the `data-old-hires` attribute to get a URL, maybe that was the issue, can you try: `$('#landingImage').attr('data-old-hires');`?

Comment: is there any way i can decode base 64 reliably? I want to try and stick with the src, which loads fine even though it's encoded, but I don't want to tax my database.